# Two level Inverter

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, inverter, three-phase

What thing determines a 2-level and 3-level Inverter as in the diagram[image]?

edit:

Level is as in 'voltage level'. I have found following good link that explains it.
http://www.elkraft.ntnu.no/~richardl/mli.html

Comment: Your question is confusing. The drawing is of a 3-phase delta motor driver with totem-pole IGBT outputs. Please clarify and/or edit your question. What do you mean by 'level'?

Comment: It’s two level. Looks up a schematic for either and compare. Google is your friend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lack of original research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

￼ [image]

This is a 3 level 3 phase driver.

It is the ability to switch to 3 linear spaced voltage levels at low Rce impedance. V+,0,V-.

They also have N level inverters.